# Typescript Super is undefined when running unit tests with jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, super

I use super.catch inside catch from derived class. And code works fine when I do manual testing. But when I run jest unit tests it says that super is undefined. Does anyone know why? And how it can be fixed?

Code example:

```
export class CustomExceptionsFilter extends BaseExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: Error | HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    logger.error(exception);
    super.catch(exception, host);
  }
}
```

Unit test example:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    filterInstance = new CustomExceptionsFilter();
    host = mockArgumentsHost;
});

it('Test', async () => {
    const baseClassSpy = jest.spyOn(CustomExceptionsFilter.prototype, 'catch');
    const httpException = new HttpException('Test exception', 404);
    filterInstance.catch(httpException, host);
    expect(baseClassSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Error I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reply')

  35 |
  36 |     logger.error(exception);
> 37 |     super.catch(exception, host);
     |                ^
  38 |   }
  39 | }
```

Comment: Any code using `super` must be the first code run in the constructor. The `logger.error` line is likely messing with that.

Comment: @HereticMonkey nope, it is not a constructor, and it works in the app. Anyway, I tried moving it to the very top and it didn't help .